# Filter dictionary of array objects

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I am trying to filter my dictionary according to user input in `UISearchController`. I have following model and array of objects.

```
struct People {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}
let first = People(name: "Atalay", id: 1)
let second = People(name: "Ahmet", id: 2)
let third = People(name: "Mehmet", id: 3)
let fourth = People(name: "Yusuf", id: 4)
let peoples: [People] = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth]
```

I put them into a dictionary to create section indexed table view with following code.

```
var dict: [String: [People]] = Dictionary(grouping: peoples, by: { (people) -> String in
    return String(people.name.prefix(1))
})
```

Above code gives me a dictionary with first letter of `People` names. Now, I would like to filter my array according to user input. However, I tried following code for filtering but it is not working as I expected.

```
let filteredDict = (dict.filter { $0.1.contains { $0.name.lowercased().contains("ata") } })
```

It returns all "A" letter section indexes like `["A": People(name: "Atalay", id: 1), People(name: "Ahmet", id: 2)]`
How can I achieve filter also my array inside dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided it was simplest to get this right by using an old fashioned `for` loop and filter each group separately

```
var filtered = [String: [People]]()

for (k, v) in dict {
    let result = v.filter {$0.name.lowercased().contains("ata")}
    if result.count > 0 {
        filtered[k] = result
    } 
}
```

Note that if you want to keep all the groups in the result dictionary just skip the `if result.count > 0` condition

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you want your final dictionary to have all the keys and only the filtered array of items as the values. If that is right, `reduce` is the tool for that:

```
let filtered = dict.reduce(into: [String: [People]]()) {
    $0[$1.key] = $1.value.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains("ata") }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is also useful for me the only thing I do not need empty keys. Even upvote your question thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve filter also my array inside dictionary?

You should have an array first, you can use `flatMap` to group all the values in your `filteredDict`

```
let array = filteredDict.flatMap { $0.value }
```

Then you just filter the array as usually

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains("ata") }
```

Comment: However, I do not need to have a new array all I need to filter my old dictionary according to user input.

Comment: I see, my bad, misunderstood the question, good that you got it working, good luck.